# Fluent NHibernate HasMany not inserting parent id

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I cannot figure out why NHibernate is inserting a child entity without the foreign key. Here are my classes

```
public class Order {
    public Order() {
        this.Notes = new List<OrderNote>();
    }

    public virtual int OrderId {get; private set;}
    public virtual IList<OrderNote> Notes {get; private set;}
}

public class OrderNote {
    public OrderNote(string noteBy, string note) {
        this.OrderNoteId = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.NoteBy = noteBy;
        this.Note = note;
    }

    public virtual Guid OrderNoteId {get; private set;}
    public virtual string NoteBy {get; private set;}
    public virtual string Note {get; private set;
}
```

Here are my Fluent NHibernate mapping files

```
public class OrderClassMap : ClassMap<Order> {
    public OrderClassMap() {
        Id(x => x.OrderId).GeneratedBy.Native();
        HasMany(x => x.Notes).Inverse.KeyColumn("OrderId").Cascase.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}

public class OrderNoteClassMap : ClassMap<OrderNote> {
    public OrderNoteClassMap() {
        Id(x => x.OrderNoteId).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(x => x.NoteBy);
        Map(x => x.Note);
    }
}
```

When I add a note to the order's notes collection and save the order, the order note gets inserted into the database without the foreign key.

```
Order order = session.Query<Order>().Where(o => (o.OrderId == orderId)).Single();
order.Notes.Add(new OrderNote("Name", "This is a note"));
session.SaveOrUpdate(order);
```

The insert statement that gets generated is this:

```
INSERT INTO OrderNotes(OrderNoteId, NoteBy, Note)
```

It should be:

```
INSERT INTO OrderNotes(OrderNoteId, NoteBy, Note, OrderId)
```

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I had this working before when the Order had a Guid as a RowId for its primary key. It still had a OrderId property and that was specified in the HasMany relationship as a PropertyRef.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `Order` property to your `OrderNote` class and set that to the order object that you're adding the note to.

Also add a `References(x => x.Order);` to your `OrderNoteClassMap`

You can also try removing the `Inverse` on your `HasMany` mapping, but I don't think this will do it.

Comment: You shouldn't have to add a property on OrderNote back to the parent because it is an inverse relationship. That would set up a bidirectional relationship.

Comment: RexM is right. For an inverse mapping you need a bidirectional relationship. The OrderNote needs to drive which order it belongs to.

Comment: So why would it work if I was using a PropertyRef as the foreign key instead of the ID?

Comment: Dude, think logically. If the child needs to drive the relation, as specified with the Inverse() keyword, then the child needs to know its parent. You obviously don't want an inverse mapping. Take it out and let the parent drive it.

Comment: I guess it's just one of those days. I knew that too, but my brain was all twisted around. Taking the Inverse() away solved it all.

Answer (score 0):

Try create an inverse relation map from OrderNote to Order and add Order property in OrderNote class.

I use to create a method like "addNote"

```
Order order = session.Query<Order>().Where(o => (o.OrderId == orderId)).Single();
order.AddNote(new OrderNote("Name", "This is a note"));
session.SaveOrUpdate(order);

public virtual AddNote(OrderNote note)
{
note.Order=this;
order.Notes.Add(note);
}
```